# Wallet, Account and Transaction with Memo

Tags: cleos, nodeos, keosd

These might be simple questions but answers can help understanding basics by new comers:
I want to understand in more details-

Wallets:

```
Wallets are something node specific I understand. So
1. Do I have to have a wallet in EOS to create Accounts? and execute the transactions?
2. How mainnet handles the wallet. I.e. is there any super wallet for all the accounts?
```

Accounts:

```
1. Do I always have to use an owner to create my account or I can pay to stake memory, cpu and bandwidth?
2. What level of control an owner would have on my account?
```

Transactions:

```
1. Everywhere example of creating transaction using some script or nodeos commands.
I am interested in RPC way of creating a transaction which can be pushed i.e. signed hex value of tx. 
I understand there is no RPC to generate a tx which can be pushed.
2. What is the maximum size of MEMO in a transaction?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Wallets:

1. No.  There are services that can create an account and pass you the keys.  As for signing, yes you need some sort of wallet to sign for you to be secure.  If you don't care about security then you could hard code a private key to a .env file and sign with eosjs: https://github.com/eosio/eosjs
2. Idk what you mean by "super wallet".  The whole idea of cryptographic signatures is the decentralized nature of it. I.e., only you know your private key thus only you can authorize transactions on your behalf.

## Accounts:

1. New accounts can only be created from pre existing accounts.  So someone who already has an account will need to create one for you.
2. With that, they can create a new Owner/Active key pair so they would not have control over your account because you would have the Owner key pair and not them leaving no tangible tie to the parent account.

## Transactions:

1. Use eosjs: https://github.com/eosio/eosjs. It integrates with the RPC api to produce a transaction given a private key.
2. Don't know off hand.